# How to save a dataframe as csv file in filefield

Tags: django, pandas, dataframe, django-models, filefield

I am trying to save a dataframe as a csv file in a model object's filefield but it is not saving it correctly, the file that is getting saved, contains some other language characters!!
please tell what I am doing wrong??

```
new_df = df.to_csv(columns=['A', 'B'], index=False)
doc.csvfile.save(f'{doc.id}.csv', ContentFile(new_df))
```

Comment: Are you sure that `doc.id` is defined? Maybe you're saving a file named `.csv`.

Comment: @JoseAntonioCastroCastro yes it is defined, problem is not that, the problem is the file that is getting saved, it is not containing the dataframe data, it containes some weird other language characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can try to save csv file with below code

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

new_df = df.to_csv(columns=['A', 'B'], index=False)

csv_buffer = StringIO()
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_buffer)
csv_writer.writerow(new_df)

csv_file = ContentFile(csv_buffer.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))
doc.csvfile.save('output.csv', csv_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a temporary file in memory using `to_csv` method of pandas dataframe.

You do not need to use any string buffer mechanism here.

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

content = df.to_csv(columns=['A', 'B'], index=False)
temp_file = ContentFile(content.encode('utf-8'))

doc.csvfile.save(f'{doc.id}.csv', temp_file)
```